# Implement jQuery Tag-it functionality in C# Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms, tags

I would like to implement a functionality similar to jQuery TagIt into C# windows forms.
Here is the link for jQuery - http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

I am thinking of creating a user control for this functionality.

Any help on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck, as there's already a container control called a `FlowLayoutPanel` that will get you 90% of the way there as a flowing tag host.

[FlowLayoutPanel Class @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx)

This control is available from the Toolbox in Visual Studio, so a good starting point would be to make a custom control based upon a `FlowLayoutPanel`, and another custom control to represent a tag based upon a `Label` or `Checkbox`, and update the drawing and behavior (in the case of a `Label`) to respond to clicks and to display the [x] to dismiss the tag.

[Label Class @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx)
[CheckBox Class @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.aspx)

After making these two controls, you will need to do additional work to make your FlowLayoutPanel-derived control add/remove Label-based controls representing the state of the tags present.

Update: One thing I missed, a `TextBox` or other input field would need to be added in place to support adding new tags.

[TextBox @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx)

Comment: I don't think you can get the kind of fade-out and collapse animation that the JQuery version has in winforms (at least not easily, as you would in WPF)

Comment: It would be extra work, but it isn't impossible to do in WinForms. Fade-Out is easy enough with drawing behavior overridden and the BackColor of each Label-item set to `Transparent` to allow drawing code to do Alpha-value painting.

Comment: How can I add Click event on the "close" image on the label?

Comment: Labels support the MouseClick event implemented by Control, so if you add a handler for it, you can add a context-specific version for your tag control. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx

Comment: How do I check if the new control getting added to the flowlayoutpannel already exists there. For Example, the user is not allowed to add two tags of same name, I have to check if its in the flowlayoutpannel before showing up there.

Comment: There's a property named `Tag` that you can read/write as a moniker to identify controls, which coincidentally is perfect for your purposes. See Control.Tag at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx

Comment: Also, you could use a `Dictionary` or `HashSet` to track the tags that are present.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TagLayoutPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    //local variables/controls
    private TextBox _entryBox;
    private Dictionary<string,string> _currentTags;

    //events
    public delegate void TagsUpdatedHandler(TagEventArgs e);
    public event TagsUpdatedHandler TagsUpdated;

    //constructor(s)
    public TagLayoutPanel()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public List<string> GetCurrentTags()
    {
        var lst = new List<string>();
        if (_currentTags != null)
            lst = _currentTags.Keys.ToList();
        return lst;
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        _currentTags = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //Entry box
        this.Padding = new Padding(3);
        this.BackColor = Color.White;

        _entryBox = new TextBox();
        _entryBox.BackColor = Color.White;
        _entryBox.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        _entryBox.KeyUp += _entryBox_KeyUp;
        this.Controls.Add(_entryBox);
    }

    private void _entryBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            var tag = _entryBox.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
            {
                this.AddTag(tag);
                _entryBox.Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set focus to the textentry box.
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        this._entryBox.Focus();
    }
    public void AddTag(string tag)
    {
        bool added = false;
        if (!_currentTags.ContainsKey(tag))
        {
            _currentTags.Add(tag, tag);
            added = true;
        }

        if(added)
        {
            Redraw();
            Notify();
        }
    }
    private void Notify()
    {
        if(TagsUpdated != null)
            TagsUpdated(new TagEventArgs(GetCurrentTags().ToArray()));
    }
    public void Redraw()
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        foreach (var tag in _currentTags.Keys)
        {
            DrawTag(tag);
        }
        AddEntry();
    }
    private void AddEntry()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(_entryBox);
        _entryBox.Focus();
    }

    public void DrawTag(string tag)
    {
        var lbl = new Label();
        lbl.MouseMove += lbl_MouseMove;
        lbl.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        lbl.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        lbl.Name = "lbl_" + tag.Replace(" ", "");
        lbl.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight;
        lbl.Text = tag;
        lbl.Tag = tag;
        lbl.Image = Resources.close_x; //Replace with your own image.
        lbl.Click += lbl_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }

    private void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lbl = (Label)sender;
        bool removed = false;
        foreach(var item in this.Controls)
        {
            if(item is Label)
            {
                if(((Label)item).Tag.ToString() == lbl.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    _currentTags.Remove(lbl.Tag.ToString());
                    removed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(removed)
        {
            Redraw();
            Notify();
        }
    }

    private void lbl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var lbl = (Label)sender;

        var startImgX = lbl.Width - 20;
        var endImgY = lbl.Height - 15;

        if (e.X >= startImgX && e.Y <= endImgY)
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        else
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;

    }
}

public class TagEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string[] Tags { get; private set; }
    public TagEventArgs(string[] tags)
    {
        Tags = tags;
    }
}
```